# Show that the abelianization functor is right exact

Tags: group-theory

I have a homework question that I do not understand for an abstract algebra class.  We have covered the first couple chapters in Dummit and Foote (on groups).  Also, I know nothing of functors besides what is given below.  We were told that we shouldn't need the formal definition of a functor.

> A functor $F$ is right exact if, given a sequence $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ that is exact at $B$ and $C$, $F(A) \rightarrow F(B) \rightarrow F(C) \rightarrow 0$ is exact at $B$ and $C$.
>
> Show that the abelianization functor F that maps $A \rightarrow B$ to $A/[A,A] \rightarrow B/[B,B]$ is right exact.

I guess my question is really, what the heck is this saying!?  This notation is a bit new, so right now I'm interpreting this as $A$, $B$, and $C$ being groups with each arrow representing a homomorphism.  If this is the case, what exactly is $F(A)$?  It looks like $F$ maps a homomorphism to another homomorphism, so what is $F(A)$ if A is a group?

Any help clarifying this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: F(A) denotes $A/[A,A]$.

Comment: Okay, since $A/[A,A]$ is a group, $F$ maps groups to groups and not homomorphisms to homomorphisms?  Then wouldn't $F$ just be another homomorphism?  Also, how then does $F$ map $(A \rightarrow B)$ to $(A/[A,A] \rightarrow B/[B,B])$?  I think I am still confused

Comment: No. F maps groups to groups and homomorphisms to homomorphisms. The authors are saying in this case the F maps $A\to B$ to $A/[A,A]\to B/[B,B]$, meaning that it maps $A$ to $A/[A,A]$, $B$ to $B/[B,B]$, and the morphism $A\to B$ to $A/[A,A]\to B/[B,B]$.

Comment: For left exact, this is wrong as discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529171/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a homomorphism of groups $f:G\to H$ one can compose with the projection map $H\to H^{\text{ab}}$ to get a homomorphism $G\to H^{\text{ab}}$. But, since $H^{\text{ab}}$ this map factors through $G^\text{ab}$ giving us a map $f^{\text{ab}}:G^\text{ab}\to H^\text{ab}$.

Explicitly

$$f^\text{ab}(a+[G,G])=f(a)+[H,H]$$

You need to show the following:

If

$$A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C\to 0$$

is exact, then

$$A^\text{ab}\xrightarrow{f^\text{ab}}B^\text{ab}\xrightarrow{g^\text{ab}}C^\text{ab}\to 0$$

is also exact.

I leave the actual verification of this to you. It's not so bad, but feel free to let me know if you'd like further hints, which I will be glad to supply.

Comment: Alright, let me try one part and see if that's right.  Showing the part involving exact at $C$.  Using $g^{ab}(b+[B,B]) = g(b) + [C,C]$, if the image of $g$ is $C$, then $g^{ab}(B+[B,B]) = g(B) + [C,C] = C + [C,C] = C/[C,C]$.  Therefore if $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is exact at $C$, then $F(A) \rightarrow F(B) \rightarrow F(C) \rightarrow 0$ is exact at $C$.

Comment: @Steve That's precisely correct. The induced map on abelianizations still has the "same image" just considered up to translation by the derived subgroup. In particular, if the map is surjective, the image of the abelianized map will be the whole group up to derived subgroup--or, in other words, the whole abelinization. What about the other exactness?

Comment: For the other, I have:  By assumption, $f(A) = ker(g)$ and therefore $f^{ab}(A^{ab}) = f^{ab}(A+[A,A]) = f(A) + [B,B] = ker(g) + [B,B] = ker(g)/[B,B] = ker(g^{ab})$, so it is exact at B as well.

Comment: Actually, if this is correct, wouldn't it suggest that the abelianization functor is also left exact?  Since there was no assumption on A, wouldn't left exactness just be the special case where $A = 0$?  However, another part of this question asks me to find a counterexample to that exact claim.  So maybe the logic I used above isn't correct?

Comment: For an example as to why $F$ is not left exact, consider $0 \rightarrow S_2 \rightarrow D_8$ where the second homomorphism, $h$, is defined as $h(e) = e$ and $h((12)) = r^2$.  Then $ker(h) = e$ which is the image of the first map.  Now, consider $F(D_8) = {e,r,s,rs}$ and $h^{ab}(e) = h(e)$ and $h^{ab}((12)) = r^2 = e/[D_8,D_8]$.  The image of the first map $0 \rightarrow F(S_2)$ is still $e$, but the kernel of the second map $F(S_2) \rightarrow F(D_8)$ is $S_2$, so the abelianization functor F is not left exact.

Answer (score 1):

This was for a comment for the questions and comments by Steve years ago under Alex's Answer. However, since it may be a bit long and directly related to the question, I think it may worth making an answer on it own right.

I would first quote the OP's work here,

> $f^{ab}(A^{ab}) = f^{ab}(A + [A, A]) = f(A) + [B,B] = \text{ker}(g)+[B,B] = \text{ker}(g)/[B,B] = \text{ker}(g^{ab})$.

In fact, the notation $\text{ker}(g)/[B,B]$ doesn't make much sense to me, since $\text{ker}(g)$ does not necessarily contain the entire $[B, B]$, so I guess what it really means is $(\text{ker}(g) + [B, B])/[B, B]$, but this is really just $\text{ker}(g) + [B, B]$ in $B^{ab}$ as a subgroup. $\text{ker}(g)+[B,B] = \text{ker}(g^{ab})$ is in fact correct, but here the surjectivity of $g$ is needed, which by exactness of the sequence $A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C\rightarrow 0$ is true.

Claim that, for the exact sequence
\begin{equation}
A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C,
\end{equation}
in general, $\text{ker}(g)+[B,B] \subsetneq \text{ker}(g^{ab})$. In fact, by definition,
\begin{equation}
b + [B, B]\in \text{ker}(g^{ab})\Leftrightarrow g^{ab}(b + [B, B]) = 0 \Leftrightarrow g(b) + [C, C] = 0\text{ 
 in  }C^{ab} \Leftrightarrow g(b)\in [C, C].
\end{equation}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation}
b + [B, B]\in \text{ker}(g)+[B,B] \Leftrightarrow \exists\ b'\in[B, B], g(b + b') = 0.
\end{equation}
Now it boils down to compare $g([B, B])$ and $[C, C]$. It is straightforward that $g([B, B]) \subseteq [C, C]$. As for the other direction, it is not necessarily true if we don't assume $g$ to be surjective, which explains your example $0\rightarrow S_2\xrightarrow{h}D_8$. If we do have $g$ being surjective, as implied by the original exact sequence $A\xrightarrow{f}B\xrightarrow{g}C\rightarrow 0$, $g([B, B])$ contains all commutators of C. Moreover, since $g$ is surjective and $[B, B]$ is normal, $g([B, B])$ is normal, so it contains $[C, C]$. Now we have established $g([B, B]) = [C, C]$, and then it follows $\text{ker}(g)+[B,B] = \text{ker}(g^{ab})$, which completes the proof.