# Is the abelianization of a subgroup $H$ a subgroup of the abelianization of a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H<G$. Then, is it true that $H^{ab} < G^{ab}$, that is, the abelianization of $H$ is a subgroup of the abelianization of $G$?

To me, it would make sense if is was indeed true. However, I do not know exactly how to prove it. For any group $G$, we know that $G^{ab} = G/G' < G$, where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. Thus, $H^{ab} < H < G$ and so by transitivity, $H^{ab} < G$ and so we obtain $H^{ab} < G$ and $G^{ab} < G$. I am stuck here...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you get $H^{\rm ab}\le H$? A quotient of $H$ need not be a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: The commutator subgroup $H'$ is normal in $H$. Does this implies that the quotient group is a subgroup of $H$?

Comment: The normality of $H'$ in $H$ simply says that the quotient $H/H'$ is in fact a group. Like I said, quotients *need not be subgroups*.  For example $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for $n\ne 0$ is always a quotient of $\Bbb Z$ but is never a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the abelianization functor is not left exact. For instance, consider the group $G$ which is the free product of two copies of $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. It has the presentation $\langle a,b | a^2 = b^2 = 1\rangle$. Its abelianization is $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)^2$. But $G$ contains a copy of the abelian group $\mathbf Z$, generated by $ab$.

(It is true, however, that abelianization is *right* exact, as it is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of abelian groups to the category of groups.)

Comment: I have never dealt with functors. Is there an easier way to picture this? Also, does this still hold if $G$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: @iHubble The phrase *abelianization is not left-exact* means, for your purposes, "even if $H\hookrightarrow G$ it doesn't mean $H^{ab}\hookrightarrow G^{ab}$." (To me, the example Marie gave is quite simple, but it might not be if one doesn't have familiarity with free products.)

Comment: Dear @iHubble, You don't need to understand functors to understand the example I gave you. I think it's quite explicit... is there something I can explain more? And no, it doesn't hold for $p$-groups. For a counter-example, take a non-abelian $p$-group, and any cyclic subgroup of it which is in the kernel of abelianization.

Comment: I haven't covered free products yet, but I really appreciate your help. At least I know this isn't true, so I won't waste my time on proving it.

Comment: Dear @iHubble, I gave you a presentation of the group in question in case you didn't know about free products. You can't get much more explicit than that! Anyways, you are welcome.

Comment: @Marie, Yes, I do get this part. The last part is fine, don't worry! I was just curious about functors. My last comment may have sounded like I didn't get the proof at all. I'm sorry about that :)

Comment: @iHubble No worries. All the best :)

Comment: @iHubble Saying that abelianization is a functor just means the following: if $f: G\to G'$ is a homomorphism of groups, then $f$ gives you a homomorphism $f^{\operatorname{ab}} : G^{\operatorname{ab}} \to G'^{\operatorname{ab}}$ sending $\overline{g}$ to $\overline{f(g)}$.  The reason that this is well-defined is that $f$ carries any commutator $[a,b]$ of $G$ to a commutator $[f(a),f(b)]$ of $G'$.

Comment: @iHubble Here is another example of how this functor can destroy inclusions.  Let $G$ be a non-abelian simple group (for example, $G=A_5$).  Then $G$ has no non-trivial normal subgroups, so in particular its commutator subgroup equals $G$.  Then $G^{\operatorname{ab}}=1$.  But if $x\in G$ is any non-trivial element, then $\langle x \rangle \leq G$ is a non-trivial abelian subgroup.  Then the inclusion $\langle x \rangle \to G$ abelianizes to $\langle x \rangle \to 1$.  This, I think, is fairly dramatic. :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to prove it is the right adjoint of the forgetfull functor to the abelian groups?

Answer (score 2):

It does not always hold. Consider the following hint.

**Hint:** For an element $a$ of the derived subgroup, $a\in G^{\prime}$, consider the cyclic subgroup $H=\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: What is this a hint for?

Comment: "Is the abelianization of a subgroup H a subgroup of the abelianization of a group G?" Take $H=\langle a\rangle$ for $a\in G^{\prime}$.