# Proof that abelianization is right exact (besides the categorical one)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the inclusion functor from abelian groups to groups. This functor has a left adjoint given by abelianization:
$$\mathsf{Ab} \underset{\mathrm{ab}}{\overset{i}{\rightleftarrows}} \mathsf{Grp}.$$

The $\mathrm{ab}$ functor is a left adjoint, so it is cocontinuous, i.e. it preserves colimits. Suppose I have an exact sequence in $\mathsf{Grp}$
$$G_1 \overset{\varphi}{\to} G_2 \overset{\psi}{\to} G_3 \to 0.$$

Then I know that 
$${G_1}^\mathrm{ab} \overset{\varphi^\mathrm{ab}}{\to} {G_2}^\mathrm{ab} \overset{\psi^\mathrm{ab}}{\to} {G_3}^\mathrm{ab} \to 0$$

is exact. I can prove this in particular using the same sort of argument one would use to show that any left adjoint is cocontinuous. But what is a more direct proof?

Thus suppose I have $g_2 \in G_2$ such that $\psi(g_2)$ is a commutator. I want to show that there is a $g_1 \in G_1$ such that $\varphi(g_1)^{-1}g_2$ is a commutator. Any ideas?

---

Note that this question is raised on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489161/show-that-the-abelianization-functor-is-right-exact) Stack question, but the answer given just says "do it yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most annoying thing about this argument is figuring out names for everything. By hypothesis, and by exactness, $\psi(g_2)$ is a commutator $[\psi(g_2'), \psi(g_2'')] \in G_3$; this is $\psi$ applied to the commutator $[g_2', g_2''] \in G_2$, and hence $g_2$ and $[g_2', g_2'']$ differ by an element in the kernel of $\psi$, hence (by exactness again) by an element of $G_1$.